# Regex VBA: match specific substring

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a followed string:

```
K9908098,G2342DF34324/234234323~234-234-234;R38724234+3D9083324T234Y 23E4234323
```

How to catch only substrings with letters and digits, e.g. `K9908098` and `3D9083324T234Y` in VBA?
This pattern `[A-Z\d]+` matches all substrings, and this `([A-Z]+\d+)+` doesn't grabs `3D9083324T234Y`.

Comment: ***How to catch only substrings*** what do you consider a substring? what are the divisors here?

Comment: @PedroLobito delimeter is any chars but not letters or digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?=\d*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z]*\d)[A-Z\d]+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OG5okR/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\d*[A-Z])` - (positive lookahead requiring that) there must be an uppercase ASCII letter after 0+ digits
- `(?=[A-Z]*\d)` - there must be an ASCII digit after 0+ uppercase ASCII letters
- `[A-Z\d]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the VBA demo:

```
Dim regex As Object, allMatches As Object, match As Object
Dim s As String

s = "K9908098,G2342DF34324/234234323~234-234-234;R38724234+3D9083324T234Y 23E4234323"

Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regex
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "\b(?=\d*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z]*\d)[A-Z\d]+\b"
End With

Set allMatches = regex.Execute(s)
For Each match In allMatches
    Debug.Print match.Value
Next
```

Output:

```
K9908098
G2342DF34324
R38724234
3D9083324T234Y
23E4234323
```